# gnomevfs or gio?

Tags: python, gio

For async IO using Python, is it preferable to rely on [`gio`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/) or [`gnomevfs`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gnome-vfs-2.0/)?

Also, which one is more "cross-platform"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use GIO.

GnomeVFS has been deprecated since GNOME 2.22, in favour of GIO.